# kernel version 3.13 even I have ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I am using 14.04.2 probably it was upgraded  over 14.04.1 but my kernel version seems still 3.13.

According to 14.04.2 it seems that 3.16. I did not understand why it was not upgraded automatically...

Comment: This is wrong. Ubuntu 14.04.2 comes with 3.16 kernel and there is nothing wrong in upgrading to this kernel. It is not good to install not supported mainline kernels, if there is no specific reason for that.

Comment: A better question would we for the OP, why do you need or want to upgrade the Kernel? Is it just for the illusion of "not stay behind" ir is there an actual requirement you need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kernels do not upgrade automatically to a next major version (like 3.13 to 3.16) through routine updates. You can do it manually by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

You can read about [HWE stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

If you want to install graphical stack from Ubuntu 14.04.2, then you can run

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

[Here is a good guide for that.](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/02/12/how-to-upgrade-to-the-3-16-lts-utopic-kernel-and-graphics-for-ubuntu-14-04/)

The Ubuntu Wiki command can remove a lot of useful packages. In some cases it removes ubuntu-desktop. So it is not good to run it. Anyway be careful and look which packages are going to be removed before agree to proceed.

After you are happy with the new kernel, you can remove 3.13 kernel meta-packages to prevent 3.13 kernels from updating. It can be done by

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

Also old kernel images and headers can be removed with Synaptic.

**Update** Now 3.19 kernel is available for Ubuntu 14.04. It can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Comment: Kernels **do** update automatically, or at least as long as you update your system with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: But you never upgrade kernel form 3.13 to 3.16 this way.

Comment: You are right, but `Kernels do not upgrade automatically this way` is misleading as one may think that kernels do not update by default at all and one has to go out of the way to update them.

Comment: I answered the question, that was asked. But you did not bother to read anything and made a wrong comment.

Comment: The package you are suggesting is a transitional metapackage which is supposed to be used when upgrading 14.04 to 14.10.

Comment: Listen, if you do not know anything about HWE, then read the link I gave and stop misleading people.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

If you want to move to a newer series of generic kernel(called [LTS Enablement Stacks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) ), you may run the following command for Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

> **Note:** It is important that you install all the packages mentioned in above command or you may break the system.

---

---

**Long answer**

Ubuntu uses it's own set of modifed kernels known as generic kernels. They are based upon original releases by the linux team which you can see on https://www.kernel.org/.

But when you install a specific version of Ubuntu, it comes with some series of generic kernel(say the 3.13.x series) and it sticks to it. So whenever you update your system using the command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

you will update your kernel automatically but you will stick to the same series(3.13.x)

If you wish to move to a newer series of generic kernel, you have to do it as mentioned earlier.

Alternately, you may want to install the latest kernel(with or without changing the current one) from https://www.kernel.org/. Instructions are available [here at kernel newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild).

Comment: Again this is wrong. The command you gave will install not only kernel, but graphical stack too. This is not good to run this command, because it may remove a lot of packets including ubuntu desktop. There are some guides how to do it correctly. But it is not related to the question.

Comment: The command is actually what the Enablement Stack guide site suggest.

Comment: That is true, but it is not correct. Here is a good guide. https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/02/12/how-to-upgrade-to-the-3-16-lts-utopic-kernel-and-graphics-for-ubuntu-14-04/