# Two 14.04.2 LTS installations, different kernel versions?

Tags: 14.04, apt, kernel

I have two installations of Ubuntu server 14.04.2 LTS, both installed from the same media (I just checked - the DVD used for both is still on the drive of one of them), but a couple of months apart. All packages appear to be up to date, but see the kernel version on one is higher than that on the other:

```
root@bud:~$ uname -r
3.13.0-55-generic

root@mud:~$ uname -r
3.16.0-40-generic
```

Why is this? Shouldn't I be running the 3.16 kernel on the first one?

Comment: They have been installed not from same media )) First from 14.04.1 or 14.04, second from 14.04.2.

Comment: I see, but /etc/issue says Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS for both of them. How do get the same kernel version for both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [kernel version 3.13 even I have ubuntu 14.04.2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/622753/kernel-version-3-13-even-i-have-ubuntu-14-04-2)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate since this isn't the result of an upgrade, but almost :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

on the first one.

But 3.13 will be supported till 14.04 EOL. For a server maybe it is better to keep it.

Or maybe it is time to run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

on both to get 3.19.

14.04.3 will come with 3.19 in about a month and support of 3.16 will come to an end a bit later.