# How does Ubuntu LTS work?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, lts, release-management

With the 14.04.3 out are the prior releases of 14.04 (14.04.1, 14.04.2) fully supported or Canonical expect users to upgrade to 14.04.3 as soon as possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific upgrade procedure from 14.04.1, 14.04.2 to 14.04.3.

If you do routine upgrades, your version will be automatically switched to 14.04.3.

There are new kernel and graphical stack introduced in 14.04.3. But they are mainly needed to support new installs on new hardware.

[Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

The old installations are fully supported.

Comment: Thanks. I am interested in the kernel version. As per you answer in this other thread it looks like the kernel upgrade needs to be done explicitly. http://askubuntu.com/questions/622753/kernel-version-3-13-even-i-have-ubuntu-14-04-2.

Comment: There is no need to upgrade kernels, if everything works OK. They will get security fixes anyway.

Comment: I am working on a container feature that needs 3.16 or above. I think 14.04.02 itself had kernel version 3.16. I am evaluating if its worth doing work arounds to support 14.04/14.04.1 or expect users to eventually upgrade the kernel (with 14.04.2 or .3). I am leaning more towards the latter now.